# Equation involving Bessel functions

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations, bessel-functions

I'm stuck on the following problem. 
Find the solutions of the equation
$$J_0(x)-J_1(x)=0,$$
where $J$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. 
Is there any method to solve it in closed form or do I have to find the solutions numerically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no closed expression for the [roots of this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=besselj%280%2Cx%29-besselj%281%2Cx%29%3D0).
We can say something about the roots that a numerical study won't tell us explicitly.

[Expand in large $x$.](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17) 
We find $\frac{1}{\sqrt{16\pi x^3}}((8x-2)\cos x - \sin x) \sim 0,$
so 
$$\tan x \sim 8x.$$ 
The right hand side is large by assumption, so the roots are 
$$\begin{equation*}
x_n\approx \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2},\tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
(These are the vertical asymptotes of $\tan x$, see the figure below.)
In fact, this approximation works well even for small $n$.

Below we give some of the roots to six digits.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_n &  (2n-1)\pi/2 \\ \hline
1 & 1.43470 & 1.57080 \\
2 & 4.68010 & 4.71239 \\
4 & 10.9832 & 10.9956 \\
8 & 23.5564 & 23.5619 \\
16 & 48.6921 & 48.6947 \\
32 & 98.9589 & 98.9602 \\
64 & 199.491 & 199.491 \\
128 & 400.553 & 400.553 
\end{array}$$

[image]

Figure 1. Plot of $8x$ and $\tan x$. Notice the curves intersect roughly at the asymptotes of $\tan x$.